# Magento: how to get the quantity of each bundle option that was ordered

Tags: bundle, magento-1.9

//Observer function
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){

```
if($item->getProductType() == 'bundle')
{     
    //Loading bundle product object
    $bundle_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

    //Getting bundle items collection
    $selectionCollection = $bundle_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection($bundle_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($bundle_product), $bundle_product);

    foreach($selectionCollection as $option) 
    {
        //Loading each bundle item
        $bundle_item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($option->getId());

        //How to get the quantity that was ordered? example:
        $bundle_item->getQtyOrdered();  //Note: I know this is wrong, this is not the correct object.
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code:

```
//Observer function $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){

if($item->getProductType() == 'bundle')
{ 
    $options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
    $bundleOption=$options['info_buyRequest']['bundle_option_qty'];
    foreach($bundleOption as $bundleItemQty){
       echo 'Bundle Item Qty='.$bundleItemQty;
    } 
}   
}
```